# How to calculate the sum of a range using a loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, numbers

How can I calculate the sum of all the values in the range between **x** and **y** ​​that were output when the function executes so that after each complete loop it repeats decrementing **y** by one until **y** will not reach **x**.
For example: `rangeSum(0, 3); --> result: 10 (0+1+2+3+0+1+2+0+1+0)`

My code:

```
function rangeSum(x, y) {
    let sum = 0;
    for (i = x; i <= y; sum += i++);
    sum += i + i--;
    return (sum);
};
```

I just don't know how to do it because I'm new to JS.

Comment: You can use a `for` loop, with an additional one nested inside the first. [Here's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) some documentation on how they work. If you get stuck, you can [edit] your question with your attempt and we'll be able to point out what you did incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

So, it looks like your example *includes* values between `x` and `y`, and runs until `y` has been decremented until it *equals* `x`, so let's work based off of that.

### Easy to read version

```js
function rangeSum(start, end) {
  let total = 0;
  let currentEnd = end;
  let current = start;

  while (currentEnd >= start) {
    while (current <= currentEnd) {
      // add to the sum
      total += current;
      // step the current value up
      current += 1;
    }
    // step the end value down
    currentEnd -= 1;
    // reset the current value to start
    current = start;
  }

  return total;
}

console.log(rangeSum(0, 6));
// > 56
```

### Digging further

I was playing around with the output of this function for fun and decided to search around a bit to see if this specific pattern of output had an existing formula. Sounds like according to [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tetrahedral-numbers/), you're looking at wanting the formula for tetrahedral numbers. If that's the case, there's a much more concise formula if you consider `x/start` from our original example to be fixed at `1` (or `0`, since adding `0` doesn't change the sum):

### Tetrahedral Numbers Forumla

```js
function tetrahedral(n) {
  return (n * (n + 1) * (n + 2)) / 6;
}

console.log(tetrahedral(6));
// > 56
```

Hope this helps. :) Thanks for the fun rabbit trail.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function rangeSum(start, end) {
  let sum = 0;

  while (start <= end) {
    for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
      sum += i;

      if (i === end) end--;
    }
  }

  return sum;
}

console.log("0~3 : ", rangeSum(0,3)); // 10
console.log("3~5 :", rangeSum(3,5)); // 22
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).